# How to get generic simple class name from scala TypeTag?

Tags: scala, types, classname, scala-reflect

How can I get the simple class name including generic using `TypeTag`? I think that the method signature should be like:

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String
```

`getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))` should return `Map[String,Int]`.

---

Things I've tried:

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String = {
  typeOf[A].typeSymbol.name.toString
}

scala> getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = Map
```

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String = {
  typeOf[A].typeSymbol.toString
}

scala> getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = trait Map
```

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String = {
  typeOf[A].toString
}

scala> getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] // It knows the full type!
```

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String = {
  typeOf[A].typeSymbol.fullName
}

scala> getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getClassName[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): String = {
    tag.tpe match { case TypeRef(_, t, args) => s"""${t.name} [${args.mkString(",")}]""" }
}

getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))

res5: String = Map [java.lang.String,Int]
```

UPDATE: Shorter version with full class names

```
 def getClassName[T: TypeTag](x: T) = typeOf[T].toString

getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int]
```

Comment: Do I have to create the string by myself? I thought maybe there is some kind of build-in method that should already do this.

Comment: It is just for the exact formating you want, you can do:
def getClassName[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): String = tag.tpe.toString

Comment: Is there some way to get the the simple class name (similar to what you get from Java's `clazz.getSimpleName`)? i.e. only `Map[String,Int]`. Using `tag.tpe.toString` gets the full name equivalent to `typeOf[A].toString`.

Comment: typeOf[java.lang.String].toString
res17: String = java.lang.String

Comment: What I meant by simple name is that it should return `Map` not `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, similar to Java's [getSimpleName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName). Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Java has that built-in, so I wonder if Scala also provides something similar.

Comment: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol.toString returns simple name as java, without "generics". I do not know exact method in scala to construct your custom representation. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my answers to this based on [Artem Aliev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722477/4751706), since it doesn't seems like Scala has this built-in. This method uses context bound syntax instead of an implicit parameter.

```scala
def getClassName[A: TypeTag](a: A): String = {
  val typeArgs = typeOf[A].typeArgs
  s"${typeOf[A].typeSymbol.name}${if (typeArgs.nonEmpty) typeArgs.mkString("[",",", "]") else ""}"
}
scala> getClassName(Map("a" -> 123))
res1: String = Map[String,Int]
```